# OFFSET must not be negative

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When we have zero results for a pagination object, and we force `?page=-1`
then we will get the error `OFFSET must not be negative`.

*-1 will get the last page by default.*

So, If you add that parameter in url you can cause an internal error always if the output is empty to paginate.

**Example:**

```
 page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)

 pagination = company.comments.order_by(Comment.timestamp.asc()).paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['COMMENTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
```

This will avoid the error, but it is annoying make always this type of validation to handle potential empty paginations.

```
 if company.comments.count() > 0:
      pagination = ...    
 else:
      pagination=None
```

My question is about the best way to handle this particular Internal server error.

Comment: Why don't you return an error 400 (bad request) if the page is < 1?

Comment: @RafaelBarros to make that i need to execute always something similar to my second example. -1 is useful if there is results to paginate.

Comment: what should the -1 do, then?

Comment: @RafaelBarros  a special page number that is used to request the last page of pagination

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're trying to do, but sqlalchemy won't evaluate this for you.

My suggestion is to calculate the number of pages yourself and then simply subtract one.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

if page < 1:
    count = session.query(func.count(Comments.id)).scalar()
    comments_per_page = current_app.config['COMMENTS_PER_PAGE']
    page = count/float(comments_per_page) -1 # gets the last page
```

Please be aware that this is untested.

Comment: i don't see any advantage over my code. What I am looking for is a generic way to handle this potential error, not some tricky hack. Probably i should post this in git of flask sql alchem

Comment: I don't think the page parameter of that function supports negative indexing like python lists would. I understand where you got that idea, and I dont disagree with you, but since that is not supported you have to handle it yourself. Or yeah, ask for the feature on github and propose the code change yourself.

Comment: Apparently this is a real problem. https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/336

Comment: Sure, but it's a very recent issue created after this question was posed, there is no precedents on this. Given the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#utilities), there was no intention or mention of supporting negative indexes. My point is: this is __not a bug__ on the lib you're using and the special behavior you expect has to be handled by you until said feature is implemented.